# Myfaces CODI DefaultErrorView - examples anywhere?

Tags: jsf, codi

I've seen a reference to a [DefaultErrorView](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage#JSFUsage-%28Security%29Errorpages) in Myfaces CODI but as usual the
documentation leaves everything to the imagination. I've really found CODI to be a
great JSF addon, but it would benefit such a lot from some examples.

Probably naively I was hoping to be able to catch the dreaded ViewExpiredException
with this code:

```
@Page(basePath = "/defaultErrorPage.xhtml")
public final class DefaultErrorPage extends DefaultErrorView {

}
```

...but all that happens after session timeout is that container security takes me
to the login page when I try to issue a get request (clicking on a h:link). Does
anyone know what I can do with this DefaultErrorView, anyone got an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaDoc of DefaultErrorView you see:

> ...
>
> The class which extends this class will also be used as error-view in case of security violations
>   (if there is no special error-view configured via
>   {@link org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.security.Secured#errorView()})

And in the Wiki you see e.g.:

> @Secured
>
> ...
>
> In case of a violation CODI will use the DefaultErrorView as navigation target (if configured).
>
> ...

and

> (Security) Error pages
>
> The following example shows how to create a default error page. It's just allowed to provide one default error page per application.
>   Instead of implementing ViewConfig it's required to implement the DefaultErrorView interface.
>
> ...

as well as the manual usage:

> ...
>
> this.viewNavigationHandler.navigateTo(DefaultErrorView.class);
>
> ...

The Wiki also links a nice example and there you find:
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/myfaces-codi-examples/source/browse/community/src/main/java/org/apache/extras/myfaces/codi/examples/community/view/config/Pages.java

**-> everything is fine with the documentation ;-)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we'll have to agree to disagree on the documentation. I read the snippets in the wiki and saw the example. I'm trying to create "one default error page per application", then I look at this line from the example: "public @Page class Login extends DefaultErrorView implements Pages" - any chance of talking me through this, is the login page the default error page? What is the significance of the Pages interface? will this be able to pick up a ViewExpiredException if I can get it working (if not, maybe it IS working and my test case is invalid). Thanks.

Comment: I'll add that I believe that JSF only throws a ViewExpiredException in the restore view phase for a POST, but I use h:link & h:outputLink (GET) for much navigation, so I'd normally expect to have to catch VEE in a phase listener, unless CODI can perform some magic in this respect. I tried the omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler but it's throwing an exception on startup on glassfish.

Comment: We are using it as default-error page for security violations and unhandled errors which are available through the JSF ExceptionHandler and therefore it works great. I don't think that it's intended to work with h:outputLink since that is just a component for corner cases, because you don't get back your state. The correct one would be h:link or h:commandLink for POST requests.